# In thermex on android, an error occurs when executing the command: apt update:

Tags: updates, termux

In termux on Android, when executing the command:

```
apt update,
```

an error occurs:

```
some index files failed to download. they have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a http caching problem. Just wait for a day and try again.
See
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/884